# Creating an object of an interface in Servlet ( Explanation Needed )?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, interface, polymorphism

I am confused with the concept interface in Servlet. I want to make sure i understand what i am working on. So any explanations will be much appreciated.

```
public class Testing implements Servlet 
{
    public void init(ServletConfig arg0) throws ServletException
   {
       /* getting some values from web.xml } */
   }

}
```

(i) init will be called by tomcat
(ii) ServletConfig is an interaface, How can an interface object can be created ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arg0` might be a reference of `ServletConfig` but it is pointing to an object of class implementing `ServletConfig`..

Eg: -

```
public interface A {
}

public class B implements A {
}

public class C {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        A obj = new B();
    }
}
```

Assume here that `interface A` is `ServletConfig`, and `class B` is the class implementing `ServletConfig`.. Now you can pass `obj` which is of type `A` and point to object of class `B`, to any method..

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly instantiate an interface. A class must **implement** that interface. Then, you can instantiate that class.

For more information and examples, check out this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/usinginterface.html

Answer (score 0):

you cant *instantiate an interface*, but you can instantiate a class which implements that interface. the *init() method* is called by the *tomcat(web server/Servlet OR JSP container)* as you said.

*ServletConfig Interface* is used during the *instatiation of your servlet*.
it has methods like *getInitParameters(string), getServletName()*...etc.
you can have a look at it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.2.1/api/javax/servlet/ServletConfig.html).

Answer (score -2):

I think the answer 3  take  a example is not correct, why don't you use extend keywrod  in interface ?  tomcat server is implimenting servelt specification container .so the ServletConfig  also is implimented